# Loading the full file in GtkTextView using Gtkmm

Tags: c++, user-interface, gtkmm3

I want to load a file, then display it's contents. I'm using Gtkmm for this and I've been able to popup the filechooser dialog. However, upon choosing the file only the last statement in the file is displayed. Here's what I'm doing:

```
case(RESPONSE_OK):
{
  std::string line,filename;
  std::ifstream fs;

  while(std::getline(fs, line)) {
     display->get_buffer()->setText(line);
  }
 fs.close();
break;

}
```

Do I need to select the textbuffer limits and if so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set_text()` replaces the contents of the `TextBuffer`. Use any variant of the [insert](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1TextBuffer.html#ac6466a773421e4d48994b65f4a1703ce) functions instead.

It may look something like  (you may need to add newlines)

```
case(RESPONSE_OK):
{
  std::string line,filename;
  std::ifstream fs;

  auto buffer = display->get_buffer();
  buffer->set_text("");
  auto insert_at = buffer->begin();
  while(std::getline(fs, line)) {
     insert_at = buffer->insert(insert_at, line);
  }
  break;
}
```

Comment: Ah okay. Is there a way I can add newlines automatically? I mean while parsing, is there a way to detect newline according to the type of code. So for Python is there a way to add lines after each statement?